# How to trigger the DOMNodeInserted event after injecting HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of our projects we load slides into our webpage with use of AJAX. After the slides are loaded I want jQuery to execute a plugin on all new injected elements automatically.

This is the code I found else where but it didn't do the trick. Also I've tried to replace `.on` function with the `.bind` function but then the whole site died and JavaScript crashes with an overflow.

```
function loaded(selector, callback) {
    //trigger after page load.
    jQuery(function () {
        callback(jQuery(selector));
    });
    //trigger after page update eg ajax event or jquery insert.
    jQuery("body").on('DOMNodeInserted', selector, function (e) {
        callback(jQuery(this));
    });
}
```

I got the problem reproduced in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssd34vkg/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A. Wolff,

Thanks your answer **solves my problem**. I have edited the loaded function to the following:

```
function loaded(selector, callback) {
    //trigger after page load.
    jQuery(function () {
        callback(jQuery(selector));
    });
    var parentSelector = "* > " + selector;
    //trigger after page update eg ajax event or jquery insert.
    jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', parentSelector, function (e) {
        callback(jQuery(this).find(selector));
    });
}
```

Also I've forked a new working JSFiddle project for anyone who wants a full working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/9t8cahqv/

Thanks,

Jop

Answer (score 2):

Event is fired on container DIV level so your selector isn't matching. You could use instead:

```
loaded(":has([title])", function(element) {
   element.tooltip();
});
/**/
jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', selector, function(e) {
   callback(jQuery(this).find('[title]'));
});
```

*### -jsFiddle-*

Comment: This looks good! I'm gonna check if this also performs good on a larger scale. If it does I'll mark your comment as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this might be, **watch for a DOM**

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (!mutation.addedNodes) return

    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
      // do things to your newly added nodes here
      var node = mutation.addedNodes[i]
      if ($(node).hasClass("some class")) {
        $(node).remove()
      }

      //or with id

      if ($(node).attr("id") == "someId") {
        $(node).remove()
      }

      //or any other selector
    }
  })
})

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributes: false,
  characterData: false
})
```

To Stop Observe, use

```
observer.disconnect();
```